# Remove original and duplicate from an array of objects - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects.

```
const arr = [
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1 },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2 },
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1 }
];
```

I would like to remove all duplicates from the array based on id. The final result should be

```
[{ title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2 }]
```

If the array is

```
const arr = [
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1  },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2  },
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1  },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2  },
];
```

The result should be an [].

This is what I tried:

```js
const arr = [{
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "rain",
    artist: "Paul",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  }
];
const uniqueScenarios = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(a => a.id)))
  .map(id => {
    return arr.find(a => a.id === id)
  })

console.log(uniqueScenarios)

const arr1 = [{
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "rain",
    artist: "Paul",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "rain",
    artist: "Paul",
    id: 2
  }
];
const uniqueScenarios1 = Array.from(new Set(arr1.map(a => a.id)))
  .map(id => {
    return arr1.find(a => a.id === id)
  })

console.log(uniqueScenarios1)
```

Please advice. I am open to lodash solutions as well. This is the final solution I am expecting. I am able to add [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a9pgna?file=ValidateFile.tsx)

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry. Updated the OP

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array

Comment: do you have only duplicates with two same `id`?

Comment: Get an object with each `id` as key and `count` for that keys as value. `filter` all the items with `count = 1`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah. I am basically pushing an object into an array and removing the duplicates

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a one-liner:

```
list.filter(el => list.filter(e => e.title == el.title).length == 1);
```

```js
const arr = [{
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "rain",
    artist: "Paul",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  }
];

const arr1 = [{
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "rain",
    artist: "Paul",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    title: "sky",
    artist: "Jon",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "rain",
    artist: "Paul",
    id: 2
  }
];


function removeDupes(list) {
  return list.filter(el => list.filter(e => e.id == el.id).length == 1);
}

console.log(removeDupes(arr));
console.log(removeDupes(arr1));
```

Comment: Could you help me out here as well? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a9pgna?file=ValidateFile.tsx I am able to add items but unable to remove them

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object and filter with the value of the hash table.

```js
const
    array = [{ title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1 }, { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2 }, { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1 }, { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2 }],
    ids = array.reduce((r, { id }) => (r[id] = !(id in r), r), {}),
    result = array.filter(({ id }) => ids[id]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina. That worked. Can you help me figure this out? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a9pgna?file=ValidateFile.tsx I am able to add items but unable to remove them to the list.

Comment: @a2441918, i have no idea. please ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417142/removing-an-already-selected-item-in-a-list-onclick-react

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, in order to avoid running an exponential loop is to save all values to a new object, and convert that object to a new array.

```
const combinedObj = arr.reduce((obj, item) => { obj[item.id] = item; return obj; }, {});
const newArray = Object.values(combinedObj)
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. They want to remove all the objects of an `id` if an `id` appears more than once.

Comment: exactly. You'll keep adding it to a reducer object by a key name: so reducer[1] = {id: 1}, overwriting previous value every time and end up with an object containing list of unique values;

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one line like this:

```
const res = arr.filter(elem => (arr.filter(obj => obj.id === elem.id)).length === 1)
```

or you can do it like this(better in terms of time complexity):

```
const arr = [
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1  },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2  },
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1  },

];

const counts = arr.reduce((counts, curr) => (counts[curr.id] = ++counts[curr.id] || 1, counts), {})
const res = arr.filter(curr => counts[curr.id] === 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run the array through [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if you should add if it does not exist, or remove using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if it does.

Snippet:

```js
const arr = [
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1  },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2  },
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1  },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2  },
  { title: "earth", artist: "Frank", id: 3  },
];

const unique = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { 
  // add if we don't have
  if (!accumulator.some(x => x.id === currentValue.id)) {
    accumulator.push(currentValue);
  } else {
    // remove if we do
    accumulator = accumulator.filter(x => x.id !== currentValue.id);
  }
  
  return accumulator;
}, []); 

console.info(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the data by id,then each item that has different `id` compared with next element and prev element should be added to the result array.

```
const arr = [
  { title: 'sky', artist: 'Jon', id: 1 },
  { title: 'rain', artist: 'Paul', id: 2 },
  { title: 'sky', artist: 'Jon', id: 1 },
  { title: 'sky', artist: 'Jon', id: 1 },
  { title: 'rain', artist: 'Paul', id: 2 },
  { title: 'test', artist: 'test', id: 3 },
]

arr.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
var res = []
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index < arr.length - 1 && arr[index + 1]) {
    if (item.id === arr[index + 1].id) {
      return
    }
  }
  if (index > 0 && arr[index - 1]) {
    if (item.id === arr[index - 1].id) {
      return
    }
  }
  res.push(item)
})

console.log(res)
```

output

```
0: {title: "test", artist: "test", id: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the items by `id`, and then use `_.flatMap()` to convert back a single array. In the `_.flatMap()` callback return an empty array if the group has more than one item:

```js
const fn = arr => _.flatMap(
  _.groupBy(arr, 'id'), // group by the id
  group => _.size(group) > 1 ? [] : group // check the size and return an empty array for groups with more than a single item
)

const arr1 = [{"title":"sky","artist":"Jon","id":1},{"title":"rain","artist":"Paul","id":2},{"title":"sky","artist":"Jon","id":1}]
const arr2 = [{"title":"sky","artist":"Jon","id":1},{"title":"rain","artist":"Paul","id":2},{"title":"sky","artist":"Jon","id":1},{"title":"rain","artist":"Paul","id":2}]

console.log(fn(arr1))
console.log(fn(arr2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Another example

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `title`, `artist`, `id` are gonna be in the same order in each of the object, one solution can be this:

```js
var arrayX=[
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1 },
  { title: "rain", artist: "Paul", id: 2 },
  { title: "sky", artist: "Jon", id: 1 }
];
var newArray = arrayX.map(i=> JSON.stringify(i)); //stringify all the objects so as to compare them
var res = newArray.filter((elem, index)=>{
  if(newArray.indexOf(elem) === newArray.lastIndexOf(elem)){
    return elem //get only those elements whihc do not have dupes
  }
}); 
var finalResult = res.map(i=>JSON.parse(i)); //parse the result to get the array of object
console.log(finalResult)
```